# How much memory space do compilers take?

Tags: memory, compiler-construction

I've read an article about BrainFuck, a slow, user-unfriendly language, where the goal only was to create the world's smallest compiler. According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck), they've brought it down to **98 Bytes** for MS-DOS.

This seems incredibly small, but it's hard to imagine for me, how small it is. When I look at download pages such as for [Java](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp), the files (depending on the operating system) are as small as **27MB**. This is huge compared to BrainFuck, but from my understandings, this also includes all the libraries that come with it.

Is there a way to look up the actual space that compilers take up? I'd love to compare BrainFuck with other compilers such as Java, C++, Assembler (maybe some more).

Comment: A good start would be the size of the compiler binary (including the size of the dynamically linked libraries).

Comment: This site is not for general curiosity questions.

Comment: @RobinGreen Where should I ask then?

Comment: I guess for this type of thing... some kind of appropriate chatroom / IRC channel? Not sure which one.

Comment: @RobinGreen I'll see what I can do. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: How long is a piece of string? Not a real question.

Comment: The 98 byte BF is an interpreter, not a compiler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to look up the actual space that compilers take up?

Sure, download said compilers and check how much disk space they take; and don't forget to take into considerations their dependencies.

It can be tricky for things like the Oracle's Java compiler, though; what you download contains a lot more than just `javac`, which is the actual module which compilers Java to Java Bytecode. That module is hiding inside the `tools.jar` file, and by examining it you can see that the compiler takes roughly 3 MB.

But then again, that compiler is written in Java so you have to have some JVM + runtime library to run it; I don't know what is the smallest package that can run it, but I'm guessing that it would be at least a few good MBs.

Even languages that compile to native code often need some runtime libraries (e.g. [the C standard library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library)) - it's your call if you want to count the size of those.

> I'd love to compare BrainFuck with other compilers such as Java, C++, Assembler (maybe some more)

None of the items in your list are compilers. Brainfuck, Java and C++ are languages; assembler is a generic name for a tool that converts an assembly language to object code. What you want to compare are specific implementations.

In any case, keep in mind that compilers are usually *not* optimized for small disk space - and even if they are, that's a minor objective. Besides, it makes little sense to compare compilers based on that alone - for example, the above Brainfuck compiler does no optimizations to speak of (and Brainfuck is an extremely low-level language anyway). Can you really compare it with a high-level language that is far more expressive and is aggressively optimized by the compiler? I don't see the point in that.